# http error 400. the request verb is invalid. iis express 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I have one Web API 2 project that was developed with .NET 4.5, but when I want build this Project with Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1, I run into this Error with IIS Express 8

### Bad Request - Invalid Verb HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.

I tried to find problem so i have searched a lot, but i couldn't found appropriate approach to fix this error, I also remove IIS Express 8 on my computer and Re Install them from Web Platform Installer 5, But again I see this error.
In witch way i can fix this error??

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be inside invalid session data (e.g. cookies).

In my case I had to clear cookies from the browser to get rid of this error message.